# Execute uninstall with C#

Tags: c#, uninstallation

I've been looking around the internet for this, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a way to trigger an uninstaller (from the Programs and Features screen) via C#? Or is this blocked by Windows for security purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [msiexec.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can simply uninstall an application with its `product code`. Using command you can set whether to show UI during the uninstallation or make it a silent uninstallation,

`string UninstallCommandString = "/x {0} /qn";`

- **/qn**: Set user interface level: None
- **/qb**: Set user interface level: Basic UI
- **/qr**: Set user interface level: Reduced UI
- **/qf**: Set user interface level: Full UI (default)

`C# code`

```
string UninstallCommandString = "/x {0} /qn";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(UninstallCommandString, "Product Code");

process.Start();
```

Comment: @GuidoVisser Make sure to give the right product code of your installation.

Comment: How to find out `product code` for the program?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [C# - Installing and uninstalling software](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20059/C-Installing-and-uninstalling-software) and [Programmatically Uninstall Programs With C#](https://sites.google.com/site/msdevnote/home/programmatically-uninstall-programs-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the executable file for the uninstaller using system.diagnostics.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/path/to/uninstall.exe", "arguments for uninstaller if needed, else don't bother with this arg");
```

It's quick and dirty and /should/ work. Hope that helps.

edit- Just realised you want to do this from the add remove software screen. I'll leave this here anyway but my mistake.